# MySQL id merge question

Tags: mysql, merge

Sorry for the vague topic but I'm having a hard time explaining this. What I'm trying to do is fetching an ID representing a post which can be posted in different categories, and I want my post to belong to all three categories to match the criteria. The table looks like this

```
id      category_id
1            3
1            4
1            8
```

What I wanna do is fetch an id that belongs to all 3 of these categories, but since they're on different rows I can't use

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE category_id = '3' AND category_id = '4' AND category_id = '8';
```

This will of course return nothing at all, since no row matches that criteria. I've also tried with the WHERE IN clause

```
 SELECT id from table WHERE category_id IN (3, 4, 8);
```

This returns any post in any of these categories, the post I want returned has to be in all three of these categories.

So the question becomes, is there any good way to look for an id that belongs to all three of these categories, or do I have to use the WHERE IN clause and see if I get 3 rows with the id 1, then I'll know that it occured three times, therefor belongs to all three categories, seems like a bad solution.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `group_concat` to get a comma separated string of your category id's and check if that contains all the categories you're filtering

<del>SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.category_id) as categories
    FROM table AS t1
    INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET('3', categories) IS NOT NULL AND
    FIND_IN_SET('4', categories) IS NOT NULL AND
    FIND_IN_SET('8', categories) IS NOT NULL</del>

### Update

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.category_id) as `categories`
FROM `table` AS t1
INNER JOIN `table` AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
HAVING
FIND_IN_SET('3', `categories`) IS NOT NULL AND
FIND_IN_SET('4', `categories`) IS NOT NULL AND
FIND_IN_SET('8', `categories`) IS NOT NULL
```

The last query would not have worked, since it is a group function the value cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause but can be used in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: I get #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous.

I guess it's because it's trying to compare t1.id = t2.id and they're ambiguous?

Comment: My bad, I didn't test the query. the `SELECT id...` should be `SELECT t1.id` since id is in both t1 as t2 because they're the same table.

Comment: Now I get #1054 - Unknown column 'categories' in 'where clause', I suppose the FIND_IN_SET doesn't understand that you labeled a table categories, sorry to bother you but you got any ideas?

Comment: I altered it abit and only went with the GROUP_CONCAT, I managed to get a result like id: 1 categories: (3, 4, 8). That's close enough, I just have to do some of the logic in the php script, that'll work. Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to say `GROUP BY id` like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE category_id = '3' OR category_id = '4' OR category_id = '8'; GROUP BY id;
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: I'm afraid this will still return posts that only has let's say 2 of the 3 mentioned categories or even 1 since WHERE IN only looks for rows that has any of the category_ids 3, 4 or 8.

Comment: That will in fact return the exact same thing as the WHERE IN(3, 4, 8), since that's exactly what WHERE IN does, tries to match any of the ids sent to it. Works the same way as OR.. This seems like such a trivial problem but it's really tricky for some reason. :D

Comment: Yeah, but the `GROUP BY` has to have some effect, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it prevents ids from showing more than once, but it's still the wrong ids. :(

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to establish the amount of categories a post appears in.

this can be done by applying `COUNT` and `HAVING` to the SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(category_id) AS categories 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING categories > 3
```

and if you wish the number of categories in your site to change dynamically you can always have an inner `SELECT` statement like so:

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(category_id) AS categories 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING categories > (
                     SELECT COUNT(category_id) 
                     FROM `categories`
                     )
```

where `categories` is the table you store all your categories information

Comment: Thanks for the input, the number of categories are alot more than three, and the number of categories I wanna search for is dynamic as well. It's a search function where the user chooses how many and what categories the user wants to search in. But I'll give this a try and see what I come up with! Thanks.

Comment: Well this makes it even simpler :), just put the categories ids in the inner select in an `IN` field and it will work as well